# how to find regex for area code of 032

Tags: php, regex

In my code below, what regex should i use in order to find the numbers that matches with **032 area code**?

```
$regex = ''; // what should i put in here?
$phone_numbers = array("02-123-4567","(032)3214567","032-1237654");

for ($x =0; $x<=count($phone_numbers)-1;$x++) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $phone_numbers[$x])) 
        echo $phone_numbers[$x] . "<br />";

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes the answer both below seems working. Cannot accept answer yet i think its because of time restriction on the time the question is posted.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there were already some answers... ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this:

```
$regex = '~^[(]?032[)-]?\d{7}$~';
```

Before `032` can be a  bracket, after `032` bracket, hyphen or nothing and than 7 numbers to the end the string.

`{7}` I used here just because you show us 7-digit phone number, if count of numbers isn't exactly 7, you can use eg. `{7,9}` or just `+`. I don't know what format have yours phone numbers exactly.

Your first 'phone number' including hyphen in the middle, if it's potentially valid format, it'd be

```
$regex = '~^[(]?032[)-]?\d{3}-?\d{4}$~';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get away with:

```
/032(.*\d){7}/
```

The important thing is that seven numbers come after it. Because any 3 digits with seven digits after them must be an area code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `[(]?032[)-]?(\d+)`

This regex matches with last 2 items in your example code.

Please also try to not ask easy questions like this here. Web has a lot of tools like [rubular](http://rubular.com) where you can practice and test your regexes.

Comment: no, this matches anywhere in the string, not just the area code section.